# Can I code and compile all type of Visual Studio Application from Command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, emacs

I am in the very first step of using Emacs as my programming environment. I run it in DOS Prompt using `emacs -nw` and do the development there. It's quite unbelievable, that I can do coding of J2EE and J2ME just using Emacs and its Eshell/Shell.

And now about using it for Visual Studio development.
Currently, I am working in a simple OpenGL application using Visual C++.NET 2008.
I haven't try to build that application from command line, is it possible?

If in J2EE and J2ME, we had the build.xml (that is an ant build file), but what is the analogue of that in Visual Studio.NET solution?

I already compiled a simple Visual Studio Console program using Command Line. It works, but what about a complete set of project???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of comments:

1. There's no need for you to use `-nw`; Emacs works fine with windows.
2. The analogue to build.xml is xxxxxx.sln, combined with the dependent project files, which are zzzzzzz.csproj.  OF course replace xxxx and zzzzz with your solution and project names.
3. you don't need the eshell or shell to compile.  You can run the compile from within emacs using `M-x compile` which is often bound to a key combo for easy access.   Mine is `C-xC-e` but I don't know if that is a broad convention or just my choice.
4. The `next-error` function works fine to move point to the next error that is reported in the compiler output. You may need a regex for error strings.  I use this:

   (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist 
      '(msvc "^[ \t]*\([A-Za-z0-9\.][^(]*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)\)(\([0-9]+\)) *: +\(error\|fatal error\|warning\) C[0-9]+:" 1 3)))

When there is already an msvc entry, you may need to

```
(let ((msvcentry (assoc 'msvc compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist )))
  (when msvcentry 
    (setcdr msvcentry '(msvc ....)))))
```

1. CEDET.  I don't have any experience using CEDET with C++ on Windows, but many people use CEDET with C++ in other environments, for code completion, code analysis, that sort of thing.

Comment: yes, the Win32 GUI version of Emacs running just fine, but I preferred (surely it's a subjective matter) `emacs -nw` because imho, it's very light. My first coding was in GW Basic at the Dos Prompt --to be precised, in the ROM--, so it's very excited to know that in my professional working age, I can do it again in a DOS Prompt, and not in a fancy GUI. I'll give a try for both answer, that seems to be so much for me. thanks

Comment: oh, yeah, I'm a big fan of cmd.exe (the "new DOS") and console apps.  I have not yet adopted powershell as my all-purpose shell, but I do use it every day.  If you don't know it, I recommend you investigate.  But I stil like the graphical look of emacs in a window. You are right - it's very subjective. To each his own.

Answer (score 5):

you have several command line tools at your service:

- [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) which builds your project from `.sln` files (which are like ant's build.xml files)
- `nmake` which is an older build-system based upon `Makefile` files
- pure `cl.exe` and `link.exe`

all you have to do is launch the visual-studio-commandline prompt OR incoporate the environment of that prompt into your own shell/powershell/emacs-environment. have a look at the `vcvars32.bat` file and what it does, it is located somewhere in the installation folder of visual2008.

you could also use other build systems ([scons](http://www.scons.org/), [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) etc) which either are standalone (scons) or create native buildscripts for your compiler (cmake, would creates `.sln`in your case).

to compile (and link) a simple binary which uses opengl you can do this:

```
 % cl /nologo opengl.cpp /link OpenGL32.lib GLu32.lib and GLaux.lib
```

take a look at a [nehe-tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01).

Comment: The only tool I know of, is just cl.exe. I think Msbuild is the thing suite my purpose. I should give that a Try. Thanks for the OpenGl things!

Answer (score 2):

In another answer to this question, [@akira said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016515/1497596):

> All you have to do is launch the visual-studio-commandline prompt
>   ***OR*** incorporate the environment of that prompt into your own shell/powershell/emacs-environment. Have a look at the
>   ***vcvars32.bat*** file and what it does; it is located somewhere in the installation folder of visual2008.

Taking that suggestion, I have created an Emacs lisp file to set up my environment in Emacs for Visual Studio 2010. To create this file, I first captured the environment settings from an ordinary command prompt and then did the same from the Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
set > set_ordinary.txt
set > set_vs2010.txt
```

Then, I found the differences between the two using a [file differencing tool for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830962/1497596). The following emacs lisp code is the result of my effort. Just copy its content into your ***.emacs*** file, or better, save its content to ***vcvars32-2010.el*** and place it in your [`load-path`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627717/1497596).

```lisp
;;; vcvars32-2010.el --- Create Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) environment settings

;; Environment settings for:
;;   Visual Studio 2010 Professional
;;   Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
;;
;;   Microsoft .NET Framework
;;   Version 4.5.50938 SP1Rel

;; Reference:
;;   C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat
;;    -and-
;;   C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat

;;; Usage:

;; Place this file somewhere in your `load-path' and add the following line
;; to your `.emacs' file:
;;
;;    (load "vcvars32-2010.el")

;;; Code:

(setenv "CommonProgramFiles" "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files")
(setenv "DevEnvDir" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\")

(setenv "Framework35Version" "v3.5")
(setenv "FrameworkDir" "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\")
(setenv "FrameworkDIR32" "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\")
(setenv "FrameworkVersion" "v4.0.30319")
(setenv "FrameworkVersion32" "v4.0.30319")

(setenv "INCLUDE"
        (concat
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include;"))

(setenv "LIB"
        (concat
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\lib;"))

(setenv "LIBPATH"
        (concat
         "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319;"
         "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB;"))

(setenv "Path"
        (concat
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VSTSDB\\Deploy;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools;"
         "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319;"
         "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\VCPackages;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HTML Help Workshop;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.0 Tools;"
         "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin;"
         (getenv "Path")))

(setenv "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" "AMD64")
(setenv "ProgramFiles" "C:\\Program Files")

(setenv "VCINSTALLDIR"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\")

(setenv "VSINSTALLDIR"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\")

(setenv "WindowsSdkDir"
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\")

;;; vcvars32-2010.el ends here
```