# load-path and load a lisp file

Tags: emacs

after setting a path for my lisp files in emacs in the .emacs file, like this

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/")

logically I should also use a load command for a specific file I guess what is that command

I tried

(load-file-name "google-c-style") with the .el added also for the file, what should be the right way to do this

however no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just `(load)`, not `(load-file-name)`.

Answer (score 6):

If the `.el` has a line like `(provide 'google-c-style)`, then all you need in your .emacs is:

```
(require 'google-c-style)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for while writing my snake game in SFML and fuzzing about mixed indentation between .cc and .h files.

Answer (score 2):

load-file-name is a variable which holds the full name of the file loaded by 'load'

use C-h-v load-file-name to read the documentation

Now, to load a file use the function 'load' - This looks for elisp source or binaries in the loaded paths

Eg: (load "google-c-style.el")

Note: There are another functions 'load-file'and 'load-library which work slightly differently. Read more about these here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html#Lisp-Libraries

Also, as mentioned in one of the answers one can also use the provide - require feature. 
Read this post to learn more about the differences between these functions(load, load-file, require, autoload)

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_library_system.html