# Run nmake from emacs on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emacs, cmake, nmake

I know there have been a few posts on the topic but didn't get a satisfying answer:

I develop C++ code and use CMake as a build system. I usually work in a Linux environment. Now I want to port my code to windows, and be able to edit and compile it within emacs.

I generate "NMAKE Makefiles" with CMake. This works fine but only if I run nmake from "Visual Studio Command Line". Visual Studio Command Line is like the regular Windows command line, with a bunch of environment variable set up.
If I run nmake from the regular windows command line, I end up with "nmake: unrecognized command" (not exactly the error message this is an approximate translation from french).

Following the old documentation in [emacs wiki](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Developing-with-Emacs.html) I found the .bat file which sets up the variables. If I run the .bat from regular command line then call nmake, it works. But when I run name from emacs, it just run the program as in a plain, regular command line, which knows nothing about nmake and the environment variables.

How can I make everything works together then?

Comment: On a side-note: With CMake you can also generate "ordinary" Visual Studio solution files and then use msbuild on the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to write a bat file, which contains the necessary settings like this:

`call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"`

`nmake`

and then call this file from emacs instead of the plain "nmake" command. This redoes the initialization every time, but should be fast enough.

Comment: Or, you could set up your environment [directly in Emacs lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23199265/1497596). With this approach, you can use any of the tools available from the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt from within Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution: launching emacs from the command line using Visual Studio Command Line, and all the variables and paths are good within emacs.

I also set up my .emacs as suggested by Cheeso in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556368/compiling-c-with-emacs-on-windows-system) .